# Orbeon Migration from 4.7 to 4.8

Tags: orbeon

I am trying to migrate Orbeon from 4.7 to 4.8. I'm getting error at following line

`<xf:instance id="Instance" src="<%=restUrl%>"/>`

The rest URL will return XML data. 
Error log is

`2015-03-30 14:58:26,258 ERROR PageFlowControllerProcessor  -     |An Error has Occurred |
2015-03-30 14:58:26,258 ERROR PageFlowControllerProcessor  -     |Got invalid return code while loading URI: http://localhost:8080/****/api/****/, 404`

I have also tried opening the rest URL in browser which was working fine and returning xml data. We are deploying Xforms as a separate application. The same code is working fine in `Orbeon 4.7` without any errors. Any changes I need to make in 4.8??

Comment: So you're getting a 404 "page not found". Is the URL in your `<xf:instance src="…"/>` a full URL, or relative URL? It is possible that the URL are now resolved slightly differently; could you try to put a full URL there (i.e. `http://…`), and see if that solves the problem?

Comment: I've tried it.. But it didn't work. It was working fine with `Orbeon 4.7`. I'm not understanding what is the problem with `Orbeon 4.8`.

Comment: So you're saying that you tried to put the full URL in the `instance src="…"`, but you're still getting a 404 error in the log, while it is working if you put the same URL in your browser? This would be strange, as if you put the full URL in the source, it should really be that URL that is requested by Orbeon Forms.